# What does the backspace character do?

Tags: javascript, html, unicode

I was reading over some of the MDN pages on regex, and came across a reference to the backspace unicode character, which intrigued me, because I wouldn't have though that backspace would have a character.

The code for it is `\U+0008`. I decided to run a test and see what it was/did, so I entered `'abcd\u0008efg'`, in a browser, which returned `"abcdefg"`. I got the same for `console.log`.

My question is, what is a backspace character, and does it do anything when rendered in html/javascript?

Comment: What character do you think gets sent when you hit the backspace key on your keyboard? Answer: the backspace char. It's not a printable character so it can't be rendered to a screen/console. How any specific program deals with it is app specific. A text editor removes the adjacent character to the left. A web browser will ignore it when it encounters it in markup as it does any other non-printable char.

Comment: Asaph: Not every key on the keyboard sends a character though. For example delete does not have a character, even though to works similar to backspace.

Comment: @TorKlingberg The character code for delete is `U+007F`

Comment: Right, there it's hiding. Still, there are no characters for Home or Page Up, right?

Comment: @TorKlingberg: Those are not characters, so they are not included in Unicode.  Do not confuse virtual key codes with text characters. `DEL` are `BACK` are characters defined by ASCII.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the backspace character is in Unicode for compatibility with ASCII. ASCII has several [control characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) that do not make much sense to have in a text file, but were transmitted to and from terminals. For example bell, escape, acknowledge, end of transport block.